# Screenshots of each page in Selenium with Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to take screenshot of each page in Selenium with Java of an insurance website and save them as a doc file. I am using Chrome drive. Someone please help me ...

I tried but it is taking screenshot of only one page. I am expecting to take screenshot of each page.